# How to use an alias to rename a field to a nested field of an object in Couchbase N1QL query

Tags: alias, couchbase, sql++

In Couchbase N1QL query language you can use the 'AS' operator to create aliases.

Say you have a document:

`{   "prop":"value" }`

You can do :

```
select prop as prop2 from `bucket`
```

The result will be:

```
{
   "prop2":"value"
}
```

What I want to do is create a nested field alias e.g.

```
select prop as nested.prop from `bucket`
```

The result should be:

```
{
  "nested":{
      "prop":"value"
   }
}
```

But I get a syntax error when I issue a query like that in the **Query Workbench    Developer Preview 1.0.2. Running Couchbase Server 4**.

According to the [Couchbase documentation](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/from.html%20this%20should%20be%20possible). It says near the bottom:

AS Keyword

Like **SQL**, **N1QL** allows renaming fields using the AS keyword. However, N1QL also allows reshaping the data, which has no analog in SQL. To do this, you embed the attributes of the statement in the desired result object shape.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT { "prop": prop } AS nested
FROM my_bucket
```